# What happens when two DNS zones intersect on the same server?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I have a DNS zone of example.com with a record of type `A` defined for `foo.example.com`. On that same server, I have another zone named `foo.example.com` with and **no A record defined** at the top of the zone. If my server receives a query for `foo.example.com`, will it return the record defined in the `example.com` zone? (Or would the search algorithm stop once it gets to the more specific zone, then answer "not found"?)

A similar question:

If I have all of the above, if I *then* set up an `A` record at the top of the `foo.example.com` zone (`@`) pointing to a different IP address, which address would be returned?

### example.com

```
foo.example.com. 3600 IN A <location A>
```

### foo.example.com

```
@               3600 IN A <location B>
```

Obviously you don't need both - I am teasing out the behavior of DNS. But is there a standard way to approach this - a standard place to put it?

I am using BIND.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When overlapping zones are defined on an authoritative nameserver, *the most specific zone* is used to provide the answer.

- A query of `example.com. IN A?` hits the `example.com` zone.
- A query of `foo.example.com. IN A?` hits the `foo.example.com` zone. If `foo.example.com` is defined in the `example.com` zone, **it will be ignored**.
- A query of `sub.foo.example.com. IN A?` hits the `foo.example.com` zone, because it is more specific for the request than `example.com`.

In your specific example, the returned value for the query would be `NXDOMAIN` because the `foo.example.com` zone does not provide an A record definition for itself.

To use DNS terminology, there is effectively a [zone cut](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-6) at the boundary between the parent zone and the more specific zone. [RFC2181 §6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-6.1) describes the proper behavior for your scenario:

> Such a server is authoritative for all resource records in a zone that
> are not in another zone.  The NS records that indicate a zone cut are
> the property of the child zone created, as are any other records for
> the origin of that child zone, or any sub-domains of it. A server for
> a zone should not return authoritative answers for queries related to
> names in another zone, which includes the NS, and perhaps A, records
> at a zone cut, unless it also happens to be a server for the other
> zone.
>
> Other than the DNSSEC cases mentioned immediately below, servers
> should ignore data other than NS records, and necessary A records to
> locate the servers listed in the NS records, that may happen to be
> configured in a zone at a zone cut.

As for which is a best practice, that's completely up to you. You can put all of your records in a single zone, or break out separate zone files for your subdomains if it would be more convenient. (say, due to them containing hundreds of records each) The one thing I would caution, which isn't very obvious, is that validation tools like `named-checkzone` typically have no awareness of subzones living on the same server and may generate incorrect warnings if the parent zone includes references to records inside the child zone. (say, CNAME aliases)